# how to get child div index of a parent div. if there are several parent div with same class

Tags: jquery, html

I have three parent div class as inner_box2. each of parent div contains more than five child div with class name inner_box_items.

On click the child div's span it should return child div index/position inside the parent div. that is I have to click in the span inside the div.inner_box_items and it should return div.inner_box_items position inside inner_box2

`

```
<div class="inner_box2">
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
</div>

<div class="inner_box2">
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
</div>

<div class="inner_box2">
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
   <div class="inner_box_items"><span>View Position</span></div>
</div>
```

`

trying like below. but not working..

```
var xyz=$(this).parents('.inner_box2').closest('.inner_box_items').index('.inner_box_items');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.inner_box_items').click(function(){
    console.log( $(this).index() ); 
    //logs the index of the element relative to its parent
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8QvpA/1/) which displays the index of the clicked element.

**UPDATE**: Question has been updated, and now wants to get the index of the parent `.inner_box_items` when the child span is clicked.

```
$('.inner_box_items span').click(function() {
    var parentIndex = $(this).parent().index();
});
```

Comment: I have to click in the span inside the div.inner_box_items

Comment: Please see my updated example. It does exactly what your question was asking.

Comment: @Mahfuz Hey, you should have added that info initially to your question.. Now what..? just update your question properly with correct information..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy .parent() seems better than using .closest().

Comment: @pmandell Closest would be reliable even if OP add that span some more levels deeper.. In that case .parent() would fails..

Comment: Or you could use the original solution and access the span inside the click handler with `$(this).find('span')`. I don't know which would be more efficient.

Comment: @Mahfuz, don't forget to accept this answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the div.inner_box_items after clicking span inside it, do like this:

```
$(".inner_box_items").each(function(){
   $(this).children("span").click(function(){
     alert($(this).closest(".inner_box_items").index());
   })       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@pmandell done well, here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sA89N/1/

```
        function cl(param){if(window.console && window.console.log){console.log(param);}}

        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('.inner_box_items span').click(function() {
                cl($(this).parent().index());
            });
        });
```